# compiler error: cannot convert from object_type<T> to object_type<T> in c++

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I have a method in a shared pointer class I am writing.

```
template<class T>
template<class Y>
shared_ptr<T> &shared_ptr<T>::operator=(/*const*/ shared_ptr<Y> &r)
{
  shared_ptr<T>(r).swap(*this);
  return *this;
}
```

Which when used in this manner

```
class Foo
{
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
};

int main(int /*argc*/, char * /*argv*/[]) {
  shared_ptr<Foo> giPtr(new Foo(1));
  shared_ptr<Bar> giPtr2;
  giPtr2 = glext::dynamic_pointer_cast<Foo>(giPtr);
}
```

Generates the following error in MSVC:

```
1>c:\users\mehoggan\documents\github\x86-applications\glextensions\smart_ptrs\shared_ptr\shared_ptr.inl(53): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'glext::shared_ptr<T>' to 'glext::shared_ptr<T>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Foo
1>          ]
1>          and
1>          [
1>              T=Bar
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>          main.cpp(28) : see reference to function template instantiation 'glext::shared_ptr<T> &glext::shared_ptr<T>::operator =<Foo>(glext::shared_ptr<Foo> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=Bar
1>          ]
```

---

***Constructors***

```
template<class T>
  shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr() : 
    _px(0), 
    _pn()
  {}

  template<class T>
  template<class Y>
  shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(Y * p) : 
    _px(p), 
    _pn()
  {
    internal::shared_pointer_construct(this, p, _pn);
  }

  // TODO: Create shared ptr from weak pointer

  template<class T>
  shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr &r) :
    _px(r._px),
    _pn(r._pn)
  {}

  template<class T>
  template<class Y>
  shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y> &r, element_type *p) :
    _px(p), 
    _pn(r._pn)
  {}

  template<class T>
  shared_ptr<T> &shared_ptr<T>::operator=(const shared_ptr<T> &r)
  {
    shared_ptr<T>(r).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }
```

***Swap***

```
template<class T>
void shared_ptr<T>::swap(shared_ptr<T> &other)
{
  std::swap(_px, other._px);
  _pn.swap(other._pn);
}
```

Comment: We need to see your constructors

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `swap` method?

Comment: The definition says it all. See up above for its definition.

Comment: Note that the second definition of the `=` operator is identical to the first one, though it specializes it for the case `Y` = `T`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any definition for `swap`.

Comment: Well, it's going to be a problem: you're std::swapping a temporary reference in disguise: `this` will be updated, but not `r`.

Comment: unless this is what you're aiming at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue comes up quite often with MSVC.

You might try using the 'injected' name, instead of the template-id of the return type:

```
template<class T>
template<class Y>
shared_ptr<T> &shared_ptr<T>::operator=(/*const*/ shared_ptr<Y> &r)
{
  shared_ptr(r).swap(*this); // note: no <T> there
  return *this;
}
```

I'm not very sure, but you might have luck defining this *in-class*:

```
template<class T> class shared_ptr
{
    template<class Y>
    shared_ptr& operator=(shared_ptr<Y> &r)
    {
      shared_ptr(r).swap(*this); // note: no <T> there
      return *this;
    }
    // ...
```

I'm guessing a bit here, but I'm thinking that the class might "appear" incomplete while defining the method body. I don't think *this should be a problem*, but MSVC two-phase lookup<sup>1</sup> is notoriously... troubled.

---

<sup>1</sup> (basically template-instantiation mechanics)

Comment: That got rid of the one error, now when I go to put in the const back in to make it sematically correct I get the following error.

error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const glext::shared_ptr<T>' to 'glext::shared_ptr<T>'